# VB.Net - Prompt To Save

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm using VB.Net 2010 Pro

This may seem like a simple question, but it's driving me bananas.

As far as I know all the way back to VB3 there was an option that one could select that would either "always save changes", "prompt to save changes" or "never save changes" when closing the IDE.  Although I've been using VB.Net 2010 for quite a while, I just noticed that it's always saving changes when ever I close Visual Studio.

I tried looking for the option to change to "Prompt Before Saving", but I can't seem to find it.  Is it still there?  If so where is it?

Comment: Maybe this will help [http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553074/file-automatically-saves-without-save-changes-to-the-following-items-prompt]

Comment: While it's not really any "help", I believe that it's saying that it's a known issue (back in 2010).

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but it must be possible to set this somewhere as I am also using VS 2010 coding in VB.NET and it always prompts me to save when I close the IDE (if not already saved).